# MVC: Keep ViewModel Value even when they're not listing on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Regarding viewmodel and view, I have a viewmodel (lets call it viewmodelA) which has 50 columns, and several views which columns are all part of viewmodelA.

Because the columns of views are highly repeated, I want to use the same viewmodel in differenct views. However, It seems that the value of viewmodel would be lost during the process.

For example, all 50 columns of viewmodelA have values, but when ‘return View(viewmodelA)’ to a 10 columns view, the other 40 columns (which does not list on the view) seem lost their values, therefore when posting back to Controller, those 40 columns become NULL.

I know I can solve this problem by creating exact viewmodel to each view, but I’m wondering if it’s possible to keep all the values, even when view not listing all columns in viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

If this is server data you use for business logic in your request processing you should not rely on what is in the model because the user can modify it before sending it.

To answer your question, if you want to keep the data you will have to use hidden inputs:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ValueYouWantToKeep)
```

Another option is to keep this data in the session.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! I know Hidden Input is an option, but I want to avoid repeating lots of hidden inputs in different views if possible. Session is also another option, I will consider this one, thank you!

Comment: It seems that keeping data in session isn't working, because I don't know which columns are listed on view so I cannot differ which column is 'real' null and which column is just not listed on view and the value should be kept.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do. If you keep data in the session it is user specific (Otherwise you can keep it in application state or cache) and you have some sort of model for it right? If you have the model you can store it in your session and get it before returning the view, that way you don't loose any data and the user can't modify it either: session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));

Comment: For Example, there is a 10 inputs view with 50 columns viewmodel, I clear one input on the view and post back to controller, then I get 1 + 40 columns of NULL. However, I cannot tell which one is the actual one I cleared, therefore although I saved all data in session, I still don't know which one I should keep and which one is supposed to be null.

Comment: In that case you will need to restructure your view model to serve the views. You can have a master model that you save in the session if you want to avoid going to the database but the model you accept in your controller should only contain the info for the view that got posted